# TextRank algorithm for Web content

Tags: python, text-mining, unsupervised-learning, nlp

I am looking for an algorithm that would be able to extract meaningful keyphrases from web articles. Each article has more than 2000 words and information is structured using paragraphs, h1, h2 tags and so on. I would like to find 2-3 word phrases that describe particular content. H1 tag plays an important role since it is like a title, but sometimes the body may contain some important information. I was thinking, that maybe TextRank algorithm could be adapted to this problem by including HTML tags and also Named Entity Recognition (NER). Do you know of any research paper in thus direction or open source implementation?
BTW. RAKE performs poorly.

Comment: You must try https://github.com/miso-belica/sumy